# HourGlass Star Pattern program in C

Tags: c

I had an interview in which I was asked to write an hourglass star pattern program. For example, if the user specifies `5` then the pattern must be like:

```
*****
 ***
  *
 ***
*****
```

If `7` then the pattern must be like:

```
*******
 *****
  ***
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
```

My coding for the pattern is:

```
for(i=n; i>=1; i--)
{
    for(j=i; j<n; j++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for(j=1; j<=(2*i-1); j++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    for(j=i; j<n; j++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for(j=1; j<=(2*i-1); j++)
    {
    printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Please don't tag your posts with random tags.

Comment: What happens if the user specifies an even number?

Comment: Only odd number from user

Comment: @AjithAj Feel free to take hints on how to solve a problem but, when it comes down to solving a problem, you need to think for yourself. Thats the only way one can learn and improve them self.

Comment: I do, but am very excited to learn, what was the mistake in my coding on this pattern.

Comment: Once you find a solution or algorithm then start coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use only **1 loop** for printing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int a=0;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    int i=0;
    char* asterisk=malloc(sizeof(char)*a);
    memset(asterisk,'*',a*sizeof(char));
    while(i<a)
    {
        if(i<=a/2)
            printf("%*.*s\n",a-i,a-2*i,asterisk);
        else
            printf("%*.*s\n",i+1,2*(i+1)-a,asterisk);
        i++;
    }
    free(asterisk);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the arguments to `main()`.

Comment: I don't need also the `return 0;`.

Comment: Why do you want to use 6 loops?

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst `(...) reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0`

Comment: @AjithAj just curious why do you need 6 loops ?

Comment: I tryed with the pattern in  for loop, But I can't do it, so only... If u use for loop, u would need 6 loop

Comment: Meninx try this program using for loop

Comment: Change `while(i<a)` by `for(;i<a;)` you will realize that it will stay **1 loop**.

Answer (score 0):

This could help. It's not the best that there is and it could be made more efficient, but it should give you an idea.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void print(int space, int star) 
{
    while (space--) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    while (star--) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void main()
{
    int star,space,i,j;
    printf("Enter number:");
    scanf("%d",&star);
    j=star/2;
    i=star;space=0;
    while (space<j || star>0) {
        print(space,star);
        space=space+1;star=star-2;
    }
    space=j-1;star=3;
    while(space>0 || star<=i) {
        print(space,star);
        space=space-1;star=star+2;
    }
}
```

Please comment if you have any doubts.
**Note**:The above code is just a sample. There are many (and far more efficient) ways to implement the pattern and it is encouraged to find a way to do so.
**Edit**:The code now prints only 1 star in the middle. Did not notice that. Apologies.

Comment: The return type of `main()` should be `int`.

Comment: You can use `putchar()` if you're just printing a single character.

Comment: In middle of the pattern I want just one star

Comment: @Mahesh, what about using for loop for this pattern.

Comment: Yes, you can replace the while loops with for loop's. Like I said before, we are here to guide you. The rest on how you want to implement, is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I found the mistake, What i did in that  code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
int i, j, n;
printf("Enter Odd value for n : ");
scanf("%d", &n);
for(i=n/2+1; i>1; i--)
{
for(j=i; j<n; j++)
{
    printf(" ");
}
for(j=1; j<=(2*i-1); j++)
{
    printf("*");
}
printf("\n");
}


for(i=1; i<=n/2+1; i++)
{
for(j=i; j<n; j++)
{
    printf(" ");
}
for(j=1;j<=(2*i-1); j++)
{
    printf("*");
}
printf("\n");
}
}
```

Thank You!!!!!!! Guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This code in two loops

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, l, n;
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i = -n; i <= n; i++) {
        if (i < 0) {
            l = i;
        } else {
            l = i;
        }
        for (j = 0; j < n+1; j++) {
            if (j < n-l) {
                printf(" ");
            } else {
                printf("* ");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (i < 0) { l = i; } else { l = i; }` What is the purpose of that?

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**